# Is it best way to use Conditional operator to assign value to fields of list than declaring new variables in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is my List "lstTelephone". I want to fill the list and values of IsSMSOptIn and IsCall fields have to be filled using the logic below.

```
lstTelephone.Add(new PatronTelephones
{
    ContactType = dr["HomeTel1Type"].ToString(),
    Extension = "",
    PhoneNumber = dr["HomeTel1"].ToString(),
    IsSMSOptIn = false,
    IsCall = false
});
```

//Logic to fill IsSMSOptIn and IsCall fields

```
if(Helper.PreferredContactType.Equals(Helper.HomeAddressType,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==true)
{
    IsSMSOptIn = Convert.ToBool(dr["IsSMSSend"].ToString());
    IsCall = Convert.ToBool(dr["IsCall"].ToString());
}
else
{
    IsSMSOptIn = false;
    IsCall = false;
}
```

Following are the 2 ways which I am planning to use.

Method 1: Using conditonal operator to get the values based on condition

```
lstTelephone.Add(new PatronTelephones
{
    ContactType = dr["HomeTel1Type"].ToString(),
    Extension = "",
    PhoneNumber = dr["HomeTel1"].ToString(),
    IsSMSOptIn = Helper.PreferredContactType.Equals(Helper.HomeAddressType,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==true ? Convert.ToBool(dr["IsSMSSend"].ToString()) : false,
    IsCall = Helper.PreferredContactType.Equals(Helper.HomeAddressType,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==true ? Convert.ToBool(dr["IsCall"].ToString()) : false
});
```

Method 2: declaring separate variables to get the values based on condition and later the new variables will be assigned to list fields

```
bool SendSMS = false;
bool MakeCall = false;

if(Helper.PreferredContactType.Equals(Helper.HomeAddressType,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==true)
{
    SendSMS = Convert.ToBool(dr["IsSMSSend"].ToString());
    MakeCall = Convert.ToBool(dr["IsCall"].ToString());
}
else
{
    SendSMS = false;
    MakeCall = false;
}

lstTelephone.Add(new PatronTelephones
{
    ContactType = dr["HomeTel1Type"].ToString(),
    Extension = "",
    PhoneNumber = dr["HomeTel1"].ToString(),
    IsSMSOptIn = SendSMS,
    IsCall = MakeCall
});
```

Please suggest which method I can prefer. Which is the best way and performance wise. It would be great if any one provides the reason why one method is better than other.

Comment: The default value for `bool` is `false` so you do not need `else` blocks

Answer (score 1):

```
var condition = Helper.PreferredContactType.Equals(Helper.HomeAddressType,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

bool SendSMS = condition && Convert.ToBool(dr["IsSMSSend"].ToString());
bool MakeCall = condition && Convert.ToBool(dr["IsCall"].ToString());
```

Seems rather clean. Using control flow to set variables to different values works as well but it's less composable. It's harder to refactor and harder to understand because you mentally have to trace multiple paths through the method.

Probably, `Convert.ToBool(dr["IsSMSSend"].ToString())` should be `(bool)dr["IsSMSSend"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I like the second method more. You don't duplicate code in this one.

Did you think about moving the creation logic into the PatronTelephones contructor ?

```
public class PatronTelephones
{
    public PatronTelephones(DataReader dr)
    {
        ContactType = dr["HomeTel1Type"].ToString();
        PhoneNumber = dr["HomeTel1"].ToString();

        if(Helper.PreferredContactType.Equals(Helper.HomeAddressType,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==true)
        {
            IsSMSOptIn = Convert.ToBool(dr["IsSMSSend"].ToString());
            IsCall = Convert.ToBool(dr["IsCall"].ToString());
        }
    }

    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsSMSOptIn { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsCall { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Notice how you can define the properties default value in their declaration. As Stephen noted, false is the default value for all bool properties/variables, so it's not mandatory here, but can help you to be sure of your property's default value.

You then just have to add a new PatronTelephones to your list :

```
lstTelephone.Add(new PatronTelephones(dr));
```

Comment: I didn't comment on the **dr["IsSMSSend"].ToString()** code. It's very error prone. If your database field is null, you'll get a runtime exception. That was not the object of your question but you definitely should be aware of this.